# Divide by 2 clock and corresponding reset generation

Tags: verilog, reset, clock, synthesis, asic

My question is about using generate a synthesizable divide by 2 clock and corresponding reset in verilog.

We can generate a divide by 2 clock as below using verilog

```
module frquency_divider_by2(
  input      rst_n,
  input      clk_rx,
  output reg clk_tx
);

always @ (posedge clk_rx) begin
  if (~rst_n) begin
    clk_tx <= 1'b0;
  end
  else begin
    clk_tx <= ~clk_tx;
  end
end

endmodule
```

My question is how to generate corresponding reset(to be used by flops using clk_tx) using rst_n

Can any one help me for the same.

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To async apply the reset and release after two positive edges of `clk_tx`. Waiting 2 positive edges stops the reset from being low for fractions of a clock period.

```
output reg rst2_n;
reg temp;

always @ (posedge clk_rx, negedge rst_n ) begin
  if (~rst_n) begin
    {rst2_n,temp} <= 2'b0;
  end
  else begin
   {rst2_n,temp} <= {temp, 1'b1};
  end
end
```

For a synchronous reset you would need to check if it was low for any section of the faster clock, during synthesis you would need to check the cdc (clock domain crossing).

```
output reg rst2_n;
reg [1:0] sync_reset_n;
always @ (posedge clk_rx) begin
  sync_reset_n[1:0] <= {sync_reset_n[0], rst_n};
  rst2_n            <= &sync_reset_n ; //AND BIT reduction
end
```

Comment: I think for async reset the clock should be clk_rx. @Morgan.

Comment: @srikanth, your absolutely correct. Updated answer. the reset should released safely on the clock domain that uses it.